# Getting this error: $Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-web-part

I have created a Visual Web Part in SP2013. But when I am adding the webpart to  the page it is giving me the following error `"$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;"`. And the error only comes when I am adding a DLL in my webpart otherwise it is running fine.

```
 <%@ Register 
TagPrefix="asp"
Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting"
Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had got the solution of that..

changed "PublicToken" to "PublicKeyToken"